# How to use FsCheck generator to generate two records of same type where one record's property differs from the other

Tags: f#, nunit, fscheck

I have this fscheck nunit test that generate two records which i then have to update so that both records always have different values for Direction property

```
[<Property( Verbose = true )>]
let ``calculate Net Worth 2`` (first:Bill,second:Bill) =
  let owing = { first with Direction = Out }
  let payCheck = { second with Direction = In }

  let compositeBill = {
    Bills = [| owing; payCheck |] 
  }
  let netWorth = calculateNetWorth compositeBill
  Assert.AreEqual(payCheck.Amount - owing.Amount,netWorth)
```

I want to not manually set Direction = In or  Direction = In , i want to use a generator to specify this.

How will such a generator look like?

I want to be left with a code like this

```
[<Property( Verbose = true )>]
let ``calculate Net Worth 2`` (first:Bill,second:Bill) =
  let compositeBill = {
    Bills = [| owing; payCheck |] 
  }
  let netWorth = calculateNetWorth compositeBill
  Assert.AreEqual(payCheck.Amount - owing.Amount,netWorth)
```

Here is what I tried with no luck

```
type BillsGen =
    static member Bill () =        
        let debit = 
          Arb.generate<Bill>
          |> Gen.map (fun dt -> { dt with Direction = Out} )          
        let credit = 
          Arb.generate<Bill>
          |> Gen.map (fun dt -> { dt with Direction = In} )
        Gen.oneof[ debit; credit ]        

[<SetUp>]
let setup () =
    do Arb.register<BillsGen>() |> ignore
```

Thank you

Here are some of my types

```
   type Direction = 
    | In  
    | Out

   type Bill = {
     Direction : Direction
   }

   type CompositeBill = {
    Bills : Bill [] 
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not experienced with property-based testing but I think you would do this by creating a new type that represents your constrained input value. You can then use `Gen.zip` in your generator to combine two generators to build a value of that type.

```
type BillsInOut = BillsInOut of Bill * Bill

type BillsInOutGen =
    static member BillsInOut () =
        { new Arbitrary<BillsInOut>() with
            override x.Generator =
                let credit =
                    Arb.generate<Bill>
                    |> Gen.map (fun dt -> { dt with Direction = In })
                let debit =
                    Arb.generate<Bill>
                    |> Gen.map (fun dt -> { dt with Direction = Out })

                Gen.zip credit debit |> Gen.map BillsInOut }
```

And once you've run `Arb.register<BillsInOutGen>()`, you can take this new type as your test argument and this property should hold:

```
let property (BillsInOut (inBill, outBill)) =
    inBill.Direction = In && outBill.Direction = Out
```

---

**Edit: another approach**

It just occurred to me that since these two bills are independent, they can be generated separately so that there's no need to zip generators together and you can get the different kinds as needed:

```
type BillIn = BillIn of Bill
type BillOut = BillOut of Bill

type BillInOutGen =
    static member BillIn () =
        { new Arbitrary<BillIn>() with
            override x.Generator =
                Arb.generate<Bill> |> Gen.map (fun dt -> BillIn { dt with Direction = In }) }
    static member BillOut () =
        { new Arbitrary<BillOut>() with
            override x.Generator =
                Arb.generate<Bill> |> Gen.map (fun dt -> BillOut { dt with Direction = Out }) }

Arb.register<BillInOutGen>()
```

A property that uses these now looks like this:

```
let property (BillIn inBill) (BillOut outBill) =
    inBill.Direction = In && outBill.Direction = Out
```

Comment: Thank you! Using your first approach, are we missing something like type BillsInOut = BillsInOut of Bill * Bill ?

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@thequickbrownfox 's answer was very helpful. But I had to make some changes in the tests. I had to create type BillsInOut = BillsInOut of Bill * Bill and specify classes to hold my tests, and from there everything was worked
The solution is shown below

```
type BillsInOut = BillsInOut of Bill * Bill

type BillsInOutGen =
  static member BillsInOut () =
    { 
     new Arbitrary<BillsInOut>() with
      override x.Generator =
        let credit =
          Arb.generate<Bill>
          |> Gen.map (fun dt -> { dt with Direction = In })
        let debit =
          Arb.generate<Bill>
          |> Gen.map (fun dt -> { dt with Direction = Out })        
        Gen.zip credit debit |> Gen.map BillsInOut 
    }


[]
type ``when analysing bills``() =

  [<SetUp>]
  member x.SetUp() = 
   Arb.register<BillsInOutGen>() |> ignore

  [<Property( Verbose = true )>]
  member x.``it should calculate net worth`` (BillsInOut (payCheck, owing)) = 
    Assert.True(payCheck.Direction = In && owing.Direction = Out)
```

The solution of generating the two bills separately didn't work out quite well